# Authentication failed, status: 503 error hortonworks HDP 2.4

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs, hortonworks-data-platform

I am getting the following error: (through command line as well as web-interface).

Useful info: 
1. Hive, HDFS, Yarn services are up and running. 
2. I can even get into hive prompt through command line and web-interface. The error occurs when I use show databases. (or click refresh symbol on database explorer of web-interface).
3. I logged in as root user, hdfs user
4. I tried changing permissions to 755 for the directory /user/root

Any help would be greatly appreciated..

------------------start of error message (copied from that of web-interface log)

Unable to submit statement. Error while processing statement: FAILED: Hive Internal Error: com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException(java.io.IOException: org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.client.AuthenticationException: Authentication failed, status: 503, message: Service Unavailable) [ERROR_STATUS].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1) Restart Atlas on Sandbox.
Step 2) Restart Hive services on Sandbox.

For me this resolved the issue.

Cheers